# what is the best way to access smart contract public variables using HardHat?

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I want to test my smart contract but don't know the way to access the public variables after the contact was deployed?
For example:

```
contract NFT is ERC721, Ownable {
using SafeMath for uint256;

bool public  isActive = False;

uint256 public startingIndexBlock;

uint256 public startingIndex;
}
```

I want to access the variable `isActive`
I have the `run.js` to deploy the contract into the local environment and here is the code:

```
    async function main() {

    const [owner] = await hre.ethers.getSigners();

    console.log(
    "Deploying contracts with the account:",
    owner.address
    );

    const contractFactory = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("ApeNFT");

    // Deploy contract with the correct constructor arguments
    const contract = await contractFactory.deploy("Mom", "MM" ,10000, 0);

    let isActive = await contract.isActive.toString();
    }
```

Here, I will never get the value of isActive. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 9):

If your settings are correct, anything that you define as public, the solidity will assign a getter function.

```
// contract.isActive()
let isActive = await contract.isActive().toString();
console.log(isActive)
```